# GDDR5X mining memory clock issue

Tags: mining, gpu, hashrate

I'm a little bit confused by the fact that my GTX 1080 which has effective memory clock of 10.8 GHz gives only ~25 MH/s while people reporting their GTX 1070 cards give up to 40 MH/s.

As far as I know there are some technical differences between memory types GDDR5X and GDDR5, but does the first really slow down ethereum mining efficiency?

Anyone else using gtx 1080 for mining purposes, maybe there are some fixes available? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting about 25 MH/s with a GTX 1070. I'm not overclocking mine but I'd be kind of surprised to see 40, averaged over time. My understanding with GDDR5X is that the specs are better but the software is just not optimized for it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I've yet to find a definitive answer as to why GDDR5X memory sucks so bad for mining, and I've been looking everywhere.  It would seem to be a simple driver problem, but it must be a big enough issue because for the 1080 Ti's, they switched back to GDDR5 memory.

I actually have 3 MSI GTX 1060 Gaming X+ which use GDDR5 memory, but get a big memory speed boost, for gaming, because the cards use architecture based on GDDR5X memory.  Which translates into a mining card that max's out at about 20 MH/s for Ether (overclocked).  A little slow for a 1060, especially one that "faster" memory.

Answer (score 0):

The answer might simply be that the block difficulty of Ethereum has increased which means everyone is getting lower hash rates now than they did when the reports you have read were written.